# Is it possible to run the Python REPL without the intro text in the beginning?

Tags: python

I'm trying to start the REPL at

```
>>>
```

instead of:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 28 2017, 18:18:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: not trying to be condescending, but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can omit the version and copyright messages by starting the interpreter with the `-q` flag (Python [3.2+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#other-language-changes)):

```
$ python -q  
>>>
```

The primary prompt (`">>> "` by default) can  be  changed  by assignment to [`sys.ps1`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.ps1):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.ps1 = ">> "
>>
```

Comment: Nice! I was going to say something hacky, like `python -ic ""`

Comment: @eddiewang: Yeah, it was introduced in Python 3.2. The `python -ic ""` thing would work on earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Eugene's answer is perfect when you're using Python 3. In Python 2, however, that option does not exist. You'll be forced to do something like `python -ic ''`. That works because `-c ''` means to execute nothing and `-i` means to do it and then enter interactive mode. A side effect of this is that it will not read your startup scripts, if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

For people using iPython, try using

```
--no-banner
```

Thanks for everyone's help!